# Obj-C: Implementing delegate of custom subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, delegates, subclass, asihttprequest

In the `ASIHTTPRequest` [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), it says:

> For more complex situations, or where you want to parse the response in the background, create a minimal subclass of ASIHTTPRequest for each type of request, and override requestFinished: and failWithError:.

So I've created a minimal subclass `MyRequest` that will handle parsing in a background thread. I haven't overridden `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate`, so my delegate class implements that protocol. However, those delegate methods pass a `ASIHTTPRequest`, which is (and I'd like to be treated as) a `MyRequest`, to take advantage of the new functionality. What's the right way to handle this with Objective-C's inheritance rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate presumably knows it's working with a `MyRequest`. In that case, it can do a checked cast in the body of the method:

```
- (void)someDelegateMethod:(ASIHTTPRequest *)sender
{
    NSAssert([sender isKindOfClass:[MyRequest class]],
            @"%s: Request %@ must be kind of MyRequest.", __func__, sender);
    MyRequest *req = (MyRequest *)sender;
    /* use |req| */
}
```